# CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder registration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cultureinfo, culture

I have a web application that is very much driven by culture. I have created some custom cultures and registered them using

```
CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder
```

Once registered do I need to register periodically or is it sufficient to register once and they will be in place on the machine for every more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling [CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.Register](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureandregioninfobuilder.register.aspx) persists the current CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder object as a custom culture on the local computer and makes that culture available to all applications. However it requires administrative privileges.

Also, From MSDN,

> A custom culture can be registered on a computer only by a user who
>   has administrative rights on that computer. Consequently, apps
>   typically do not create and install custom cultures. Instead, you can
>   use the CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder class to create a special-purpose
>   tool that an administrator can use to create, install, and register a
>   custom culture. After the custom culture is registered on a computer,
>   you can use the CultureInfo class in your app to create instances of
>   the custom culture just as you would for a predefined culture.

This simply means that your website should not create custom cultures. The application pool identity is rarely admin (and it's recommanded not to be). Create a separate installer/program/script that will create these custom cultures, using CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.

Comment: Yes and I have this, thanks. Question I have is does need to be only once or does it expire and need to be run regularly?

Comment: The Register method stores a custom culture as a file on the server, in the Globalization subdirectory of the Windows Directory. Once the file is created, it will remains on the server until there is a call to the Unregister method.